# Magento 2: How to override lib/web/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js?

Tags: magento2, overrides, wysiwyg, tinymce

I made some changes in **tiny_mce_src.js** to avoid wrapping elements in `<p>` tag in **wysiwyg** editor (I set `forced_root_block : ''` in **11277 line**).

Is it possible to override `./lib/web/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js` in Magento 2?

Comment: Please specify magento version.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal It's Magento 2.1.5

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

yes if you want to override it inside an adminhtml theme
you can override it by putting the overided files inside web of that theme
forexample create a theme called test

> /app/design/adminhtml/test/web/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js